# What is the different between Data Store and Data Source in Visual Studio Blend 2013?

Tags: expression-blend, blend

I found the different are:
**Data Store:**
- Property-Value pair
- No random data

**Data Source**
- Property-Value pair under Collection
- Random data

Does these 2 feature is helper to create XAML?
What different between them and what's the aims of usage?
Thanks you.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `DataSource` is used for sample data. You can use sample data to have some data to work with when designing your application. In the end you will replace the sample data with real data when running the app. More on sample data [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee371157%28v=expression.40%29.aspx).

A DataStore is used in combination with `Behaviors`, [Data behaviors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff723901%28v=expression.40%29.aspx) to be more specific. Sometimes you need to store a property to make a design work, a simple counter for example that triggers a change in design when a certain limit is reached. You could add this to your `ViewModel` and bind it to your view, but sometimes it will just clutter the ViewModel.